# Date filter in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Wondering why some of the dates one some entries don't get grouped into the 'years' categories like the other entries do? For example, under 2022, there is an entry for December with some other date into, including the month and day. As you can see in the photo, not all the entries are listed under 2022. These dates will output unique data and have no interdependencies.
The input data that is used to create the filters
[image]

Comment: Edit your answer to show the input data that is used to create the filters, otherwise it is difficult to judge what is going on. One explanation is that they are in different format, e.g., "2022-11-30" etc. is in text format and the others are really a date format, then I have exactly the same issue.  Thus, If you bring them in a real date format, it should work.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: the edit still does not show the input data you use only the filters.

Comment: .. can it be that that (non-grouped, outliner cells) date is formatted as 'text' rather than 'date' ?